# trouble in connecting PostgreSQL on Ec2 instance from remote system thru Python

Tags: python, linux, postgresql, psycopg2, ec2-ami

I am trying to connect ec2'instance Postgres DB from my PC (windows) thru Python.

[image: Error I am getting]

Steps i have taken before this : 
I am running Amazon Linux AMI EC2 instance.
[image: inbound rules of the running instance]

I have installed Postgres SQL following the below command :

```
sudo yum install postgresql postgresql-server postgresql-devel postgresql-contrib postgresql-docs

sudo vim /var/lib/pgsql9/data/pg_hba.conf

# TYPE  DATABASE        USER            ADDRESS                 METHOD

# "local" is for Unix domain socket connections only
local   all             all                                     trust
# IPv4 local connections:
host    all             all             0.0.0.0/0                 trust
# IPv6 local connections:
host    all             all             ::1/128                 trust
```

My pg_hba.conf file:

```
sudo vim /var/lib/pgsql9/data/postgresql.conf
listen_addresses = '*'          # what IP address(es) to listen on;
                                    # comma-separated list of addresses;
                                    # defaults to 'localhost'; use '*' for all
                                    # (change requires restart)
port = 5432                             # (change requires restart)


sudo su - postgres
psql -U postgres 
sudo service postgresql start
CREATE DATABASE hacker_news WITH OWNER postgres;
```

I am not sure where i am doing wrong for the connectin g the postgresSql db in in my  running ec2 instance.

Any help /Directions appreciated.

Basically i want to connect to my postgresql db n my remote device so that i can insert data base into it by python.

Thank you .

Comment: Can you connect to it with psycopg2 if you run the code on the ec2 instance?

Comment: @JacquesKvam No I am not able to connect it throws me `OperationalError: could not connect to server: 'Connection timed out (0x0000274C/10060)
 Is the server running on host "ec2-107-22-157-62.compute-1.amazonaws.com" (107.22.157.62) and accepting
 TCP/IP connections on port 5432?'`  Please Correct me if i am giving the right parameters : `conn = psycopg2.connect(host='ec2-107-22-157-62.compute-1.amazonaws.com',
                        user='postgres',database='hacker_news',sslmode='require')`

Comment: Did you try using "localhost" instead of the public IP? Maybe this is dumb, but did you check if postgres is running on the machine?

Comment: @JacquesKvam Np ! But i donot want to connect with my Localhost .. i want to connect my ec2 instance host

Comment: @JacquesKvam Yes i am able to connect and get result on ec2 instance by running as localhost (inside ec2 instance) , but while conneccting from remote system .. i am stil getting the error ....

Comment: @JacquesKvam Thanks it working .. I am able to connect now!!